# Is Brahmastra ever used?

Tags: mahabharata, history, brahmastra

A documentation by History channel says that, Mohenjo-Daro could be affected by Brahmastra, they provide enough proofs like the rocks are melted at high temperature and turned out to magma state and feel like glass, this can be achieved only if the material is exposed to extreme heat. If so it is true, who could have used Brahmastra and Why?